# jQuery timepicker 'Object does not support this property or method'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've been looking for a timepicker and finally found this one, [timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/), the problem is I can't get it to do anything..

here's my page:

```
<head runat="server">
<title>VTC Request Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="Css/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css"type="text/css" />
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

          $("#datepicker").datepicker({});
          $('#StartTimeTextBox').timepicker({});
       });  
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<label>Date:</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" />
    </div>
    <div><label>Start Time:</label>
<input type="text" id="StartTimeTextBox" name="StartTimeTextBox" value=""/>
    </div>
```

the datepicker works fine, but the timepicker errors out- 'object doesn't support this method or property'

Comment: Does the timepicker-addon script depend on the widget script?

Comment: Did you try on different browsers?

Comment: Are you sure all script files are loaded properly when the page is loaded? Could be a script filename typo you missed.

Comment: Just a thought.  Is that an Internet Explorer error?  If so, please make sure you have a DOCTYPE for your page and you're not running in quirks mode.  That's often the problem whenever a client has a page that's supposed to work, but gives out these strange errors.   Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're missong Jquery slider

> jQuery Timepicker Addon
>
> Use
>
> - To use this plugin you must include jQuery and jQuery UI with    datepicker and slider
> - Include timepicker-addon script
> - now use timepicker with $('#selector').datetimepicker() or $('#selector').timepicker()

Look at this page

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

Comment: that was exactly the problem.. can't believe I overlooked that.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are simply completely messed up with script referencing.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/datetimepicker_css.js"></script>
```

No need to re-reference separate jquery ui files if you include the full library (jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.js)