# 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'timepicker'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, timepicker

While running my project in Internet Explorer i caught up with this message " **0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'timepicker'**" and indicated that the error occurs on one of js files that is attached to the project. 
the error points to this line on the js file
***--> $('.timepicker-default').timepicker();***  there is no other problems with this as the datetime picker works fine. The project runs fine on chrome and Firefox. This happens only with IE explorer (IE 11 , version : 11.0.9600.17351)

Comment: [did you google your error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852336/jquery-timepicker-object-does-not-support-this-property-or-method)

Comment: Yes , got something similar but didn't help me out with my problem.

Comment: Please make sure your datetime picker library reference added before calling the function. IE11 has developer tools (press F12 before you load the page and see the library is loading - network section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully managed to solve my problem. Not sure whether my approach is right or wrong. what i did is ... 
1. Removed most of the References from my child pages and put it on to the Master/Layout Page.
2. Added **jquery-1.9.1.min.js** , **jquery.js** files only on my child pages
3. Added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.default-date-picker').datepicker({
                format: 'mm-dd-yyyy'
            });
</script>
```

Now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

From IE 11 menu tools.. compatibility View Settings,  remove the web sites that causing the errors from the list